# Camera's LED is on, but no picture

Tags: camera, raspicam

Trying to connect original `Raspberry` camera to Pi 3. I have camera's red LED on, but no picture.

```
vcgencmd get_camera



supported=1 detected=0
```

What are the next steps I must do in order to find the problem?

UPD:

Connections are checked.

I'm using a Python script to get the picture:

```
from picamera import PiCamera
from time import sleep

camera = PiCamera()

camera.start_preview()
sleep(10)
camera.stop_preview()
```

Command `raspistill -o test.jpg` brings:

```
mmal: Cannot read camera info, keeping the defaults for OV5647
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)
mmal: Failed to create camera component
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Camera is not detected. Please check carefully the camera module is installed correctly
```

UPD.

I bought a new camera(V2) and got the same result. Should I do a special install for the V2 camera since I had V1 previously?

Comment: What display are you using? Preview does not work on GPIO displays for example.

Comment: Try it with `raspistill -o test.jpg`. If that still doesn't work it's either incorrectly connected or a dead camera (I've seen several instances where the LED comes on (on the old V1 module) but the camera doesn't respond to the firmware)

Comment: Trying to get picture to standard HDMI monitor.

Comment: I have updated message body with `raspistill -o test.jpg` output. Does it means camera is dead?

Comment: I bought new camera V2 and got the same result. Should I do special install for V2 camera since I had V1 previously?

Comment: There's no difference in installation between V1 and V2 cameras. It's possible (although very rare in my experience) that you've got a dead CSI port on the Pi. To confirm this, however, you'd need to test your modules on another Pi.